# Корректен ли данный код, чтобы сделать зеркало сайта?

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите, этот код корректен? или что-то тут лишнее осталось от настроек вордпресса по умолчанию и что-то можно убрать или заменить? Нужно прописать правильно, чтобы сделать зеркало сайта с www.mysite.net на mysite.net

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.net$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.net/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

Comment: Я не гуру по `.htaccess`, но мне кажется `RewriteEngine On` надо ставить выше остальных редиректов.  А вообще есть хорошая [сборка снипетов](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#force-non-www) для `.htaccess` на `github`. В целом у вас так же, как и там предлагается.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, рад буду если ещё кто-нибудь поделиться свои мнением..